# How to display a message?

Tags: node.js, express

At the moment, for example, when deleting a record using Postman, a hang occurs and no error is displayed there. How can immediately display this error in Postman if it appears?

```
module.exports.remove = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        let category = await SprCategories.findOne({ CATEGORY_ID: req.params.CATEGORY_ID })

        category.destroy().then(() => {
            res.status(200).json(category)
        })

    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

errorHandler:

```
module.exports = (res, error) => {
    res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message ? error.message : error
    })
}
```

Comment: What does “errorHandler” send?

Comment: try this in catch section return res.status(400).send({
   message: e
});

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa Added by

Comment: @MalikAsad Did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Unhandled rejection Error` is coming from `category.destroy()`.

To solve this since you are already using an `async funcion`, `await category.destroy()` if it fails your `catch` block will take over

```
module.exports.remove = async function (req, res) {
  try {
      const category = await SprCategories.findOne({ CATEGORY_ID: req.params.CATEGORY_ID })

      await category.destroy()
      res.status(200).json(category)
  } catch (e) {
      errorHandler(res, e)
  }
}
```